# Generar número float en un rango pequeño con la clase random en java

Tags: java, random, float

Intento generar un número aleatorio en un rango pequeño, pero utilizando la clase random sólo conozco el rand.nextFloat, que sólo crea números decimales entre el 0 y el 1. Y me gustaría que el rango fuera entre 70.00 y 99.99, ¿es posible hacerlo utilizando el rand?

Comment: Multiplica el random por 29.99. Tendras un valor entre 0 y 29.99. Sumale 70 y tienes el valor que buscas.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución a tu problema es este código :

Primero de todo realiza el siguiente import :

`import java.util.Random` o  `import java.util.*` si también tienes un Scanner o quieres ahorrarte problemas...

Después de realizar el import te dejo este código de ejemplo para que lo entiendas correctamente y puedas aplicarlo a tus necesiadades :

```
double max = 99.99;
double min = 70.00;
double random = min + Math.random() * (max - min);
System.out.println(random);
```

Comment: Cualquier duda escribe un comentario!